# How can I force git to prompt me for the email address to use, if not set in the repo config?

Tags: git

Let's pretend I am a contractor that occasionally works on 2 projects simultaneously, (one might be maintenance, one might be in development)

Occasionally I have to work on a new repository, and I forget to set the email address to use in git, so it defaults to the globally set email address.

How can I manage this better?

What happens if I only define email address at the repo level? will git complain, or will it happily commit without an email address defined?

How can I make checking out a brand new repo, prompt me for an email address?

Is it possible for it to prompt for one of 2 different company 'profiles' config files instead?

I'm prone to making this mistake over and over, months apart, so I usually forget things that have to be set up on new machines, or commands that need to be run instead of the default git ones.

This also occasionally affects me when I work from home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to unset your local user.email and enable the user.useConfigOnly option. This option is available [from git 2.8 onwards](https://blog.github.com/2016-03-28-git-2-8-has-been-released/#dont-guess-my-identity).

```
git config --global --unset-all user.email
git config --global --add user.useConfigOnly true
```

This configuration is per-computer, so you'll need to set that on each computer you're cloning to.

With this set, commits will fail because your email is not set and autodetection is disabled.

```
$ git commit -m "Test"
fatal: no email was given and auto-detection is disabled
```

Then for each new repository, configure your email address locally:

```
git config --local --add user.email "bob@nosuchemail.net"
```

Comment: Thanks! your answer helped lead me to https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/04/04/multiple-personalities-in-git which also goes over having multiple git configurations per project / directory.

Answer (score 0):

Combined with @NightSicarius answer it is possible to use "Conditional Includes" in a git configuration.

From the comments on https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/04/04/multiple-personalities-in-git

> This is even easier now with the addition of conditional includes in
>   Git v2.13. You can use the same folder structure/.gitemail files that
>   you mention but reference them from the top down rather than
>   relatively.
>
> If the include condition ends in a trailing “/”, the path is matched
>   recursively to all subdirectories, making the whole structure work.
>
> [includeIf “gitdir:C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/jm/”] path =
>   C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/jm/.gitconfig
>
> More information can be found at:
>   https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes
>
> And an example at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43884702/6798110